# SQL Select INNER JOIN tabela contatos unir todos os telefones em único registro relacionado

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estou enfrentando o seguinte dilema: possuo 3 tabelas (Fornecedor, Representante e Contatos) segue imagem da representação das tabelas.
[image: Tabelas]

E a seguinte query:

```
select *
from Fornecedor F 
  inner join Representante R as on R.id_provider = F.id 
  inner join Contato C as on C.id_provider = F.id or C.id_representative = R.id 
group by F.id
```

A tabela Fornecedor é a entidade principal. A tabela Representante faz referência à tabela Fornecedor e a tabela Contato faz referência às tabelas Fornecedor e Representante. Ou seja, a tabela Contato e a tabela Representante dependem da tabela Fornecedor para existir.
Um Fornecedor pode ter zero ou mais Contatos. A tabela Representante também segue essa regra. Na tabela Contato há identificadores para saber se o número salvo é celular ou fixo e o campo type identifica a tabela "dona" do número.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que no resultado da consulta retorne os números de telefones referente aquele cadastro em um único registro sem duplicar os registros para cada número de telefone, ou seja, queria que um único resultado retornasse o telefone e o celular do fornecedor e do representante sem duplicar registro para cada telefone.

Comment: Sua aplicação garante que `Contato` e `Representante` referenciam o mesmo fornecedor ou podem ser diferentes fornecedores?

Comment: Sim, garante sim.

Comment: Um fornecedor pode ter um ou vários representante  um representante pode ter apenas um único fornecedor um fornecedor pode ter zero ou vários contatos um representante pode ter zero ou vários contatos

Comment: Avalie se a função de agregação `GROUP_CONCAT` para o campo telefone atende a suas necessidades.